# Can't kill all child processes using SIGTERM

Tags: c++, pipe, fork, termination

My program has the following parent child layout:

```
int main() { 

std::vector<pid_t> kids;
pid_t forkid = fork();

if (forkid == 0) {
//child process
    pid_t fork2 = fork() 
    if (fork2 == 0) {
      // child process 

     }else {
      //parent
      kids.push_back(fork2);
     }
}else {
// code here
   kids.push_back(forkid);
}

// Not killing the fork2 process - only the first process(forkid) is terminated

for (pid_t k : kids) {
    int status;
    kill(k, SIGTERM);
    waitpid(k, &status, 0);
}


  }
```

I am not able to kill the child process (fork2) - the first process gets terminated. The `kids` vector seems to only contain the process id of the first process. Never gets the pid of the child process.
What am I doing wrong here. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is, child1 would have to kill child2, (since child2 pid is in the kids vector in child1), but child1 is killed before it can kill child2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::vector<pid_t> kids;
pid_t forkid = fork();
```

`fork()` creates a ***complete duplicate image*** of the parent process as its child process. Emphasis on: ***duplicate***.

This means that, for example, the child process has its ***very own*** `kids` vector, that has nothing to do, whatsoever, with the parent process's original `kids` vector.

Since this is the very first thing that happens in `main`, this is really no different than you running this executable twice, individually as two distinct and separate processes, instead of `fork`ing off a process. You can't expect the `kids` vector in one of the two processes to have any effect on the `kids` vector in the other one.

The first child process creates a 2nd child process, and also adds the 2nd child process's pid into its own `kids` vector. But that's just the first child process's `kids` vector.

The only process id that the original parent process's `kids` vector ends up having is the first child's process it, so that's all you get to `SIGTERM`.

Your options are:

1. Restructure your logic so that ***both*** child process get created by the parent process, so it, alone, puts their process ids into its `kids` vector.
2. Instead of using `fork` use multiple execution threads, and the same process. However, neither `std::vector`, nor any other C++ library container is thread safe. A massive pile of code will need to be written to properly synchronize the threads, in order for things to work themselves out correctly (not to mention that the analogue for the `SIGTERM`, with respect to multiple execution threads, needs to be invented in some way).

The simplest alternative is the first one.

Comment: Third option, not that I am advocating for it but it may be warranted depending on use case: grandparent creates parent, parent creates child; parent has `SIGTERM` handler that kills child before it dies itself; grandparent kills parent when it wants. Each process only handles its own direct child(ren).